# SharePoint 2013 - WSPBuilder web-parts error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-addin, wspbuilder

I am new to SharePoint. I have SharePoint 2013 server installed on one server and vs 2010 on another pc. I am using WSPBuilder (SharePoint WSP tool) to create web parts. I have installed the WSPBuilder (SharePoint WSP tool) on my pc and created a web part using wspbuilder. My web part will contains only text message. The web part is successfully builed and comined. It will generated the .dws file. I have uploaded this .dws file on SharePoint 2013 server. When I try to access the .dws file, I am getting the below error.

```
The file you imported is not valid. Verify that the file is a Web Part description file (*.webpart or *.dwp) and that it contains well-formed XML.
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

DROP WSPBuilder, not a good thing, you need to do the webparts with visual studio, thats it.  It will create all the files for you, also you have to create a Feature that deploys the webpart.

WSPBuilder is WAY OOOOOOOOOLD!, Avoid it
Last Update was on May 9th **2009**
https://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/

**The descriptions says:
A SharePoint Solution Package (WSP) creation tool for WSS 3.0 & MOSS 2007**

use this tutorial for 2010:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413295(v=office.14).aspx

for 2012 this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231551.aspx

Comment: I have understand the solutions as you suggested. But I can not use vs 2010 as my SharePoint server and vs present on different PCs. Please can you help me?

Comment: You have to use visual studio, sorry. And as I said it doesnt matter, Visual Studio is never installed on servers, thats a common practice.  You install a virtual machine on your local environment, in that VM you add Windows 2008 Server, Sql Server and Sharepoint and Visual Studio, now you have a full working virtual server to develop.  Once you develop you can package a WSP  and send it to the IT team for installation.  But again, you need VS in your development environment.

Answer (score 1):

dont listen to Luis, well most of it ;) ,

wspbuilder is brill for 2003 and 2007! for 2010 make sure you have the correct version!

you need WSPBuilder Extensions 2010 BETA 1.4 which is at the bottom!

http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/releases/view/30858

also, your using 2013 which is different to 2010 but you could give it ago! things have changed from 2010 to 2013 in how the webparts are made!

> Creating a Visual WebPart in SharePoint 2013 is different than what it
>   was available in SharePoint 2010. In SharePoint 2010, Visual WebPart
>   was made of a User Control and a Webpart file which were used to
>   define Controls and define properties of the webpart. In SharePoint
>   2013 however the Visual WebPart template has Changed. Both the User
>   Control and WebPart classes are merged to Create one template. Also,
>   now you have one Visual WebPart template that can be used to Create
>   both Sandbox and Farm solution. In this post we will look at detailed
>   steps on how to create a Visual WebPart Farm solution and add the wsp
>   to your SharePoint site.

I do agree with Luis on the fact that you should be using vs now as its come along way from the 2003 days! but to say its old doesnt mean its no good!

have this for reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261736.aspx

for 2013 webpart creating step by step:

http://blog.youngmoony.com/post/2013/01/28/SharePoint-2013-HOW-TO-CREATE-A-CUSTOM-WEBPART-IN-SHAREPOINT-2013.aspx

in the example above you can test it by playing the code (debug) goto the temp folder and ull see the created wsp! copy that and use it on the 2013 server ;)

Comment: the fact of just not using VS its just wrong.  I have been on SP arena for years and I havent seen the first customer or person that doesnt use VS, WSP builder works? probably it will, but its not a good practice, and I avoid all bad practices.

Comment: you could say that ;) for me who develops many webparts under deadlines, having wspbuilder does it for me at a faster rate! its still the same as if i was to do it with vs! also would have to manually edit web.config ect or add it into code, whereas wspbuilder does it for you when it builds the wsp ;) means more development time less debugging issues! from a business its a godsend! for me its vital in 2007 and 2003! i still use vs for development! lol wspbuild just builds the wsp for you ;)

Comment: lol, then I dont get it, you can right click package on vs, piece of cake. why use that thing>?

Comment: there is alot it does in the background that vs doesnt do and you have to do in code or manual!

Comment: I would like to know what, because after I create vs webpart, I just add the webpart to a feature, package and thats it, I dont have to do anything manual.  I meant all of this for 2010, for 2007 no idea

Comment: Dear Luis and ali, thanks for your feedback's and suggestion. My questions is how to resolve the error I am getting. Please Can any one help me to resolve this error.

Comment: @MAHESHALLE the issue is you could get that error when using 2007 type webpart in 2010 and vise versa! so my point is developing the webpart in wspbuilder for 2010 can also lead to that message in 2013! use the method that iv outlined in my answer! gothrough the link and get the wsp that way!